# Difference between the fundamental solution and the Green function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A lot of sources (books, internet courses, articles etc.) deal with just one of the two: Green function, and the fundamental solution. I wasn't able to find a distinction, but I suppose there is one. However both seem to be defined for a differential operator $D$ as follows:

$G(x-y)$ such, that: 
 $DG(x-y)=\delta(y)$

So what's the difference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fundamental solution solves $DG(x-y)=\delta(y)$ on the entire space $\mathbb R^n$.

Green's function solves $DG(x-y)=\delta(y)$ on some domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$, and satisfies some homogeneous boundary condition. (Most often, but not always, the Dirichlet condition).

The [lecture notes](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~sijue/greensfunction.pdf) by Sijue Wu present the derivation of Green functions for the Laplacian from the fundamental solution. You should be able to see how these objects are related, and how they are different: in a nutshell, to find Green's function we add a smooth solution of the PDE to the fundamental  solution, so that the sum satisfies the boundary condition.