# What is the difference between the impulse response, Green's function, fundamental solution and elementary solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, fundamental-solution

See for impulse response vs Greens function

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363845/45664

but no answer was given although there were many good comments.

See for Greens function vs fundamental solution

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377683/45664

but again no answer was given although there were many good comments.

Also see

[Difference between the fundamental solution and the Green function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/596112/147776)

where an (the?) accepted answer is given for fundamental solution vs greens function.

Then see L. Schwartz,"Mathematics for the Physical Sciences" p.281  where for operator L the elementary solution, E, is essentially defined as $L(E)=\delta$

and I. M. Gelfand, "Generalized Functions" p. 107, where the elementary solution is again essentially defined as $L(E)=\delta$

also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution where the fundamental solution is given as $L(F)=\delta(x)$

Finally, I remember seeing somewhere that the impulse response of L is given as $L(I)=\delta$

**My question is:** *What is the difference between the impulse response, Green's function, fundamental solution and   elementary solution?*

If no differences, why so many names for the same thing?

Note that in all cases the equation with the operator is non homogeneous. A forcing function, $\delta$, is required.

See for almost the same question but with additional different functions (except for Green function):

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20797/45664

See also:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/596502/147776

[Green's Function / Impulse Response Confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2432092/147776)